# How can I search for an Item in the array using C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

If the item is in the array, count how many times it is stored in the array and what are their respective array locations.

How can I add this output in my program.

Here's my code...

```
int array[15]={28,3,16,4,3,16,5,8,4,12,5,4,8,21,40};
int x=0;
int done=0;
int item;

cout<<"Input an item to be searched:";
cin>>item;

while(done!=1&&x<15)
 {
  if(item==array[x])
   {
     cout<<"Found item"<<item<<" in the index of " <<x;
     done=1;
   }
  else
    {
     x++;
    }
 }
cout<<" item "<<item<<" is not found";
```

This should be the output:

Item to be searched: 4
number of occurrence : 3
array locations : 3 8 11

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: College assignment with no effort.

Comment: But still I have the effort for asking some help

Comment: Ayaw nalang gud mo ug palag lisud biya ning programming!

Answer (score 1):

Take an array `location` of size `15`. Go through array `array` and if element found then store that index to `location`.

```
int k = 0, location[15]
while(x < 15)
{
    if(item == array[x])
    {
        location[k++] = x;
    }
    x++;
}
if(k > 0)
{  
    cout << "Found item" << item << " in the index of:\n" ;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
         cout << location[i] << endl;  
    }  
}
else 
     cout << "Item not found\n" ;
```

Comment: Would be better to use std::vector since you don't know how many occurences are going to be. This might not be the problem with this example, but in case of large array this approach is not feasible.

Comment: @user3564091; Yes. Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the head

```
int result[15]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Try inserting the following code into existing

```
while(x<15)
 {
  if(item==array[x])
   {
     result[x] = 1;
     // cout<<"Found item"<<item<<" in the index of " <<x;
     done++;
   }
   x++;   
 }
```

And show the result

```
cout << "Item to be searched: " << item;
cout << "number of occurrence : " << done;
cout << "array locations : ";

x = 0;
while(x<15)
 {
  if(result[x]==1)
   {
      cout << x << ' ';
   }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Loop through all the locations like this:
for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++) {
    if(array[i] == item) {
        count++;
        //save the locations in an array, or a string already
    }
 } cout << blabla
```